# Expression of a hypergeometric sum

Tags: combinatorics, summation, computational-mathematics, hypergeometric-function

Let $q,\ell, M \in \mathbb{N}$
How to get a better expression of the following sum:
$$
\sum_{m=0}^q\binom{q-m+\ell-1}{q-m}\binom{2m+M-1}{2m}
$$

Comment: This just looks like a mess to me. Are you expecting some particular form? It is clear one could rewrite this expression as the difference of two generalized hypergeometric series, but what do you actually want?

Comment: Just insert the values $q,\ell$ and $M$. Then it should no problem to calculate the sum.

Comment: I am not familiar with this type of expressions. Ideally I have to find a better expression of this sum in terms of $q, \ell, M$.

Comment: @user124297 Do you have an example with values of $q,\ell$ and $M$ where you cannot calculate the sum?

Comment: [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_(m%3D0)%5Eq+((q-m%2Bl-1)+choose+(q-m))*((2m%2BM-1)+choose+(2m))) end up with the generalized hypergeometric function

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, but it is not helpful at all, as I need to work with this function further...

Comment: @user124297 It seems there is no "simpler" expression. How can we help you now?

Comment: I wondering if it is possible to somehow split this sum into fewer easier terms

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/112667/1960